# Unsupported Message Type - SecurityList + FIX50SP2

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to capture- `SecurityList` message(35= y)

Receiving message in log file as:

```
8=FIXT.1.19=000036635=y49=XXXXXX56=XXXXXX34=352=20190204-10:41:59.758369=2320=1322=R1560=0393=951301=DGCX_PRECIOUS_METALS1300=GOLD_FUTURES893=N146=255=[N/A]48=546822=8167=FUT200=201906541=20190529231=32107=DG-20190529562=1561=115=USD120=USD7555=26555=[N/A]48=546922=8167=FUT200=201904541=20190327231=32107=DG-20190327562=1561=115=USD120=USD7555=26510=180

8=FIXT.1.19=9735=j34=349=XXXXXX52=20190204-10:42:00.29356=XXXXXX45=258=Unsupported Message Type372=y380=310=178
```

First thing - Not able to capture this message in fromApp() method.

Second- Using `message cracker,` cracking  it as, but not coming in this method:

```
public void onMessage(SecurityList message, SessionID sessionId)
              throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue {
        log.info("Recieved SecurityList");
    }
```

XML file looks like which has same sequence of message coming as this :

```
<message name='SecurityList' msgtype='y' msgcat='app'>
   <component name='ApplicationSequenceControl' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityReportID' required='N' />
   <field name='ClearingBusinessDate' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityReqID' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityResponseID' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityRequestResult' required='N' />
   <field name='TotNoRelatedSym' required='N' />
   <field name='MarketID' required='N' />
   <field name='MarketSegmentID' required='N' />
   <field name='LastFragment' required='N' />
   <component name='SecListGrp' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityListID' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityListRefID' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityListDesc' required='N' />
   <field name='EncodedSecurityListDescLen' required='N' />
   <field name='EncodedSecurityListDesc' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityListType' required='N' />
   <field name='SecurityListTypeSource' required='N' />
   <field name='TransactTime' required='N' />
  </message>
```

Conf file :

```
UseDataDictionary=Y
AppDataDictionary=C:\conf\FIX50SP2.xml
```

What can be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message is cracked using `Message Cracker`, need to check if `MessageCracker` class is cracking that particular message.

The older version might miss out on some messages.

Using newer version `quickfix-messages-fix50sp2-2.0.0` jar where `MessageCracker` class was cracking this message solved the problem.